# Cannot stop pulseaudio in ubuntu studio 18.04

Tags: pulseaudio

I do not want pulseaudio to start automatically, as I need jack to start first so that it can capture alsa. For some reason, pulseaudio keeps respawning:

```
$ ps aux | grep pulseaudio
gdm        883  0.0  0.1 1156168 11452 ?       S<l  23:06   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
ben       1334  0.0  0.1 1442008 13352 ?       S<l  23:06   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

**What I've tried:**

I've set `respawn = no` in `/etc/pulse/client.conf` (nothing in `~/.config/pulse` either)

I've disabled pulseaudio service and socket

```
systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.socket
sudo systemctl disable pulseaudio
```

Also why is `gdm` starting its own pulseaudio instance? If I try to kill that it respawns also. I looked in gdm's homedir and there is no pulse config. I also tried masking pulseaudio socket/service for my user and gdm. The thing keeps respawning and I have no idea why.

Comment: Another strange thing is, whenever I kill pulse, my X session seems to freeze entirely until pulse respawns. I can move my mouse, but I can't click anything or alt+tab.

Comment: Please add this in the question itself. And did you try using `kill` command?

Comment: `I've set respawn = no in /etc/pulse/client.conf` but it should be `autospawn = no`.

Answer (score 3):

I realized I wasn't seeing the `;` prepending each line in `/etc/pulseaudio/client.conf`, which was commenting out the line. Uncommenting by removing `;` before `autospawn = no` fixed it.